# Getting function as string then run it

Tags: python, string

I have script like:

```
from string import digits, uppercase, lowercase, punctuation
from itertools import product

chars = lowercase + uppercase + digits + punctuation

for n in range(1,  2+1):
    for comb in product(chars, repeat=n):
        print ''.join(comb)
```

it works fine. Imagine `chars` is giving by an external user so:

```
import sys
from string import digits, uppercase, lowercase, punctuation
from itertools import product

chars = sys.argv[1] # sys.argv[1] is 'lowercase+uppercase+digits+punctuation'

for n in range(1,  2+1):
    for comb in product(chars, repeat=n):
        print ''.join(comb)
```

when run script.py:
It has not the result when you say:

```
chars = lowercase + uppercase + digits + punctuation
```

Now how can I get the previous result?

Comment: When you say `chars = 'lowercase+uppercase+digits+punctuation'`  the program doen't work. because lowercase and etc are functions not string... how can the the python these are not string and thy are functions

Comment: Let me update the question

Comment: Well, yes... because they're strings. If you want the attributes of `string` with those names, you must tell Python as much. Trivial research will tell you how.

Comment: A hint: `string.lowercase == getattr(string, 'lowercase')` assuming that you have imported `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary mapping the user input to the corresponding strings.

```
>>> input_to_chars = {
...     'lowercase': lowercase,
...     'uppercase': uppercase,
...     'digits': digits,
...     'punctuation': punctuation
... }
```

Construct `chars` from the user input like this:

```
>>> inp = raw_input('what character sets do you want? ')
what character sets do you want? lowercase+uppercase+digits+punctuation
>>> chars = ''.join(input_to_chars[i] for i in inp.split('+'))
>>> chars
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Or with the hint from @schwobaseggl in the comments:

```
>>> import string
>>> inp = raw_input('what character sets do you want? ')
what character sets do you want? lowercase+uppercase+digits+punctuation
>>> chars = ''.join(getattr(string, i) for i in inp.split('+'))
>>> chars
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

The dictionary solution is easy to extend, the `getattr` solution is good if you don't want to extend your program to accept user inputs which are not attributes of `string`.